databricks get job metadata
I am listing all databricks jobs in my department with job name, creator, notebook path and maybe other details. I am using databricks API but it seems not working and I can't find much help from internet so far.
    import requests
    import pandas as pd
    import math
    import datetime
    import json

    baseURI = 'https:xxxxx'
    apiToken = 'xxxxxx'
    params = {
         "job_id": '981462083700076'
    }
    endpoint ='/api/2.1/jobs/get'
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {apiToken}'}

    response = requests.get(baseURI + endpoint, headers=headers, params=params)

    response_json = response.json()

I got this error:
    JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
    File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py:971, in Response.json(self, **kwargs)
        970 try:
    --> 971     return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
        972 except JSONDecodeError as e:
        973     # Catch JSON-related errors and raise as requests.JSONDecodeError
        974     # This aliases json.JSONDecodeError and simplejson.JSONDecodeError

    File /usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py:346, in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
        343 if (cls is None and object_hook is None and
        344         parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
        345         parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
    --> 346     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
        347 if cls is None:

    File /usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py:337, in JSONDecoder.decode(self, s, _w)
        333 """Return the Python representation of ``s`` (a ``str`` instance
        334 containing a JSON document).
        335 
        336 """
    --> 337 obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
        338 end = _w(s, end).end()

    File /usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py:355, in JSONDecoder.raw_decode(self, s, idx)
        354 except StopIteration as err:
    --> 355     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
        356 return obj, end

    JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
    File <command-4139801197528004>, line 17
         13 headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {apiToken}'}
         15 response = requests.get(baseURI + endpoint, headers=headers, params=params)
    ---> 17 response_json = response.json()

    File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py:975, in Response.json(self, **kwargs)
        971     return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
        972 except JSONDecodeError as e:
        973     # Catch JSON-related errors and raise as requests.JSONDecodeError
        974     # This aliases json.JSONDecodeError and simplejson.JSONDecodeError
    --> 975     raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)

    JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)


This question is similar to: How to call databricks rest API to list jobs run. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ZachKing ok, it looks similar but not solving my issue. I have come up with some code but needs help to get it to work. Thanks.

@thoteielder the JSON parse error is likely due to the API response being an error code. Can you check your response status code before trying to use .json() ?

Now it works, I changed nothing. I have no idea what happened. BTW the status code was 404, i did print it out, now it is 200.

@thotwielder i have provided the solution. please check if it helpful to you.

Just giving it has an answer so that it helps community to find better solution.
As @Zach King said before converting it to json need to check response code.
Use below code to handle this exception.
if response.status_code == 200:
    try:
        response_json = response.json()
        print(json.dumps(response_json, indent=4))
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print("Error decoding JSON:", e)
else:
    print(f"Error: Received status code {response.status_code}")
    print("Response text:", response.text)

According to this documentation only 200 status code has the body/content, so you need to handle the exception other than 200 status code.
